# Three.js models loading issue

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to load gltf model into my page using the following code :

```js
            var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader().setPath('models/football_goal/' );
            loader.load('scene.gltf', function (gltf) {
                gltf.scene.traverse( function( node ) {
                 if ( node instanceof THREE.Mesh ) { node.castShadow = true; }
                } );
```

The problem is when the I open the page the browser fail loading the model and downloading the scene.bin file instead.

This is only on my device and other collaborators don't have this issue.

Comment: Are you hosting your application on a local web server? Or do you open it from file?

Comment: @Mugen87 Yes I'm hosting the application on a local web server

Comment: That might be a problem of the web server's configuration. Please have a try with node.js and [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server).